# Contribution form displaying in footer of WordPress site after form submission

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress, contributions, forms

On a Wordpress site which uses the theme "Enlightenment" I have used civicrm shortcode to embed a civi Contribution form on a wp page. All is well until I click the Confirm Contribution button.. the next page that is returned (Contribution confirmation page) has the form results replicated in the wp/enlightenment footer

a part of the footer as it appears before contribution submission: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2WYW.jpg

same part of the wp footer as it appears after submission..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByiCL.jpg

I've studied the page source for these two cases and it appears that civi's

It seems that the problem is related to the civContribution webform submission - any ideas on why the proper style inheritance would be lost after form submission and how/where I can fix this problem?

I realize this is a case of Enlightenment probably doing something the civiContribute doesn't expect but since all is well before form submission I suspect that there could be a civi way to fix this.

Comment: I'm under the gun to get this working, and would be happy if I could just get the Contribution form working with connectivity to the CiviCRM db without the wordpress theme.. i.e. i'd be happy with plain html at this point. Is there any way to route entirely around the wordpress theme just for the Contribution webform?

Comment: What version of Civi are you using? There were significant improvements to WP integration in 4.6, if you aren't on that already...

Comment: CiviCRM 4.6.8 and WP 4.2.4

Answer (score 2):

I installed the plugin Multiple Themes (https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/) which allows me to set a different wp theme (e.g. Twenty Fifteen) just for the /?page=CiviCRM pages. Now I no longer have the replicated webform problem. The Contribution page appears has a different look & feel but I'm ok with this. Thanks so much for the help Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Could you [set a Civi basepage](https://civicrm.org/blogs/haystack/working-civicrm-46-wordpress) and apply an extremely cut down template to that specific page?

You'd need to create a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) in your theme directory. Create the file, then fill it with the most basic content possible. So something like:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Basic Template */ ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 
                the_content(); 
        } // end while
    } // end if
    ?>
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
<html>
```

Then on the base page, change its template to 'Basic Template' and update.

This would apply to *all* pages that Civi uses, so is inherently pretty hacky.

Comment: I just went to my civi basepage and I don't see a way to eliminate the Wordpress markup other than what I did on the Page I created that I refer to above in which I inserted Civi shortcode pointer to Contribute page I configured. not sure how the base page would help..

Comment: updated my comment to show how to add a custom template.

Comment: ok, I did what you indicated.. the Enlightenment theme doesn't have a page.php but it does have an index.php so I created a file called index-plain.php and pasted in your code. I added in "echo 'Test';" where you have  // Post Content here. I edited the /CiviCRM base page, unchecked the enlightenment sidebar/feature hook boxes and selected 'Basic Template' from the Template dropdown, and indeed when I View page I just see "Test" printed at the top left. Forgive me for being such a newb but how do I now insert my Contribution form into this scenario? thank you..

Comment: If that's the base page being used by Civi pages, then when you go to your contribution form it should now display using this template. If not you can force it: use the code from 'The wpBasePage' at https://civicrm.org/blogs/haystack/working-civicrm-46-wordpress into your functions.php file - but change 'my-template-name.php' to 'index-plain.php'.

Comment: I added the code you suggested (with index-plain.php replacement) to the Enlightenment theme's functions.php file and then opened my Contribution page by going to Manage Contributions and clicking on Links->Live Page but I just see my blank page with 'TEST' at the top - the Contribution form does not display..

Comment: oops, sorry - missed a function. Replace your "echo 'Test';" with "the_content();". I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for catching that. I updated my index-plain.php with your updated code above.. (adding a '/' to the '<html>' at the end) and now I get this civi error: "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Invalid value passed to getPayment function
Return to home page."